# A topological quotient on a subset of the positive reals $\Bbb R^+$.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, quotient-spaces, collatz-conjecture

Let $X=\Bbb Z[\frac16]^+$ be the positive dyadic and ternary rationals, with their topology inherited from $\Bbb R$ and let $p^{\nu_p(x)}$ be the highest power of $p$ that divides $x$.

Now make a topological quotient $X/{\sim}$ of $X\subset \Bbb R$ that says a set $X'\subset X$ is open if for all $x\in X'$ the set also contains $\lim_{n\to\infty}f^n(x)$

Where $f^n(x)=x+(1-2^{-6n})\cdot2^{\nu_2(x)}\cdot3^{\nu_3(x)-1}$

Here $f:\Bbb N\times X\to X$ and $n$ indicates compositions of $f$.

**Question**

Does $X/{\sim}$  make sense as a quotient space?  Is it well-defined?  In particular, I'm aware that the condition I've defined is not clearly (to me at least) an equivalence relation and therefore may not define a quotient.  Does taking a topology, and then to declare some subsets are open, define some other form of new topology from the original?

**Motivation**

All being well, under this topology, the Collatz graph will have finitely many connected subgraphs if and only if the quotient space is disconnected.  But my topology is limited at best and I need to learn whether all is well.

[A note on graph-connectedness here. Under this topology, graph-connectedness is largely equivalent to topological connectedness.]

Comment: Some of your notation doesn't make sense to me. Is $f^n$ given by the formula you wrote down, or is it the $n$-fold composition of some $f$? Those things do not seem consistent. If it is the latter, what ensures that the limit you write down exists? You talk about forming $X/\sim$, where $X$ inherits the topology of $\mathbb R$, but then you describe a totally different topology on $X$ *in terms of $\sim$*.

Comment: @MeesdeVries regarding $f$, the two cases you ask about are not mutually exclusive, and in this case they coincide, so $f^n(f^m(x))=f^{m+n}(x)$

Comment: @MeesdeVries regarding the existence of the limit, the limit is $x+2^{\nu_2(x)}3^{\nu_3(x)-1}$ which follows from the fact that $2^{-6\infty}=0$. So for example $f^\infty(1)=\frac43$

Comment: @MeesdeVries regarding your third query, this really is the subject of the question. I begin with one topology $(X\subset\Bbb R^+)$ and I then say: "Take some subsets of it and declare them open, and make that a new topology".  In other words, unite them with the sets of $X\subset\Bbb R^+$ that are already open, to give a new definition of what the open sets are.  I'm asking whether it makes sense to do this, and if so how I make sense of it and what is the right terminology.

Comment: If the only value you are interested in is $f(x) = x + 2^{\nu_2(x)}3^{\nu_3(x)-1}$, I would remove the "intermediate" functions from the post; they only confuse things. You can certainly add "new open sets" to a topology: simply take your topology $\tau$, add the sets you want to be open, and then take the smallest topology generated by the result. This is not a quotient space though.

Comment: Thanks @MeesdeVries .  That is very helpful.  Do you have any pointers how I actually put the statement "take the smallest topology generated by the result" into action in practical terms? Incidentally, regarding the irrelevance of $f$.  What if I set $x\sim y$ whenever there exists $n,m\in\Bbb N$ such that $f^m(x)=f^n(y)$.  Does that get me anywhere, or does it do the same thing as "take the smallest topology..."?